# WCF on Bigrock.in/.com or Godaddy Shared Windows Hosting

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, hosting, shared-hosting

I was wondering whether a `wcf service` would be allowed to be hosted on http://Bigrock.in or http://bigrock.com [windhows shared hosting](https://www.bigrock.in/web-hosting/windows-hosting.php)  or with [godaddy's shared windows hosting](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=9009).

Anyone have any experience with the above and also what are possible the limitation's on these hosts ?

If it isn't allowed there, can someone suggest some hosting plans where I can host `wcf service`? (for normal usage, nothing heavy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is allowed at Bigrock. Send us an email on sales[at]bigrock[dot]com and we will help you with any details you need.